# copy file in google drive using pydrive or google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, storage, google-drive-shared-drive

```
function copyFolderContents_(source, target) {
  // Iterate files in source folder
  const filesIterator = source.getFiles()
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    const file = filesIterator.next()

    // Make a copy of the file keeping the same name
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target)        // need to find python function replacing THIS LINE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  }
}

const toCopy = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
const copyInto = DriveApp.getFolderById('')
const newFolder = copyInto.createFolder(toCopy.getName())
copyFolderContents_(toCopy, newFolder)
```

I trying to rewrite this app script into python, which only copies the file but not the folder into another locatioN

is there any pydrive or vanilla HTTP restful API that could replace `file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target)` ?

After visiting  [ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)  , seems this restful API doesn't have a target that I could specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parent[]` parameter in the request body of [Files:copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy) is the same as the destination in [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination).

### Example:

Here I have a folder named **68759008** which has the sample document:

[image]

and here is the destination folder I want my sample document to be copied.

[image]

### Using API Explorer:

**Request Parameter:**

[image]

*In the request parameter, I only inserted the file ID of the sample document*

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "parents": [
    "Insert Destination folder ID here"
  ],
  "name": "68759008_TEST_DOC_COPY"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

There are two options to obtain the parent ID or the destination folder ID:

- You can go to the destination folder and copy the string after the `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/`
- Use [Files:list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), find the file name and the `mimeType` should be `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`

**Files:list Example:**

[image]